# PYTHONPATH in Eclipse not working

Tags: java, python, eclipse

I can do `import module from module` if I have a .py file sitting in my src folder. I have a data folder that is located in the same parent folder as src. I have added the data folder do the PYTHONPATH, but it won't load it. Any suggestions?

Comment: More detail is needed - please describe exactly how you changed `PYTHONPATH`, what are the contents of this "data folder," where and how you're doing your `import`, and what the response is from Eclipse.

Comment: Holy balls, way to necro a thread from almost a month ago. Solved this a long time ago.

Comment: Excellent. In that case it might be helpful to either add and accept your own solution or delete the question, so that it drops off the "unanswered" queue.